# Generics type inference fails?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

#### Example A

Study the following snippet:

```
public class ExampleA {
   static class Pair<F,S> { }

   static <F,S> Pair<F,S> anyPair() { return null; }

   static <F,S> void process(Pair<F,S> p1, Pair<F,S> p2) { return; }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Pair<String,Integer> p = anyPair();

      process(p, anyPair()); // doesn't compile
   }
}
```

Can someone explain why type inference works for the assignment to local variable `p` but not for the second actual parameter to `process`?

---

#### Example B

This is perhaps simpler to understand:

```
public class ExampleB {     
   public static <E> void process(Set<E> s1, Set<E> s2) { return; }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      process(new HashSet<String>(), Collections.emptySet()); // doesn't compile
   }
}
```

Same question: why doesn't it compile?

I'd hope that `Collections.emptySet()` would just work for *ANY* parameterized `Set` type.

Comment: Nice one again, polygenelubricants :)

Comment: Good news! These examples now compile in Java 8. Maybe target typing saves the day?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second call to `anyPair()` does not have any way to determine it's types and so it defaults to `<Object, Object>`.

The compiler is breaking `process(p, anyPair());` into it's pieces and processing each individually.  When it does this, it needs to process the arguments first to determine their types, which can then be used when processing `process`.

When it goes to process `anyPair()` there is no type information available for that piece, because it does not know that it is part of `process` at that point.  It defaults to `<Object, Object>`, which then causes a type mismatch when looking at `process`.

The same thing happens with your second example.  `Collections.emptySet()` needs to be processed by itself, but has no way of determining the Types needed.

There are 2 ways to solve this:

The first is to give the compiler the information it needs for type inference the same way you did with the first call to `anyPair()`, by storing it in a temporary variable with the correct type.

The second (thanks to @BalusC) is to use `ExampleA.<String, Integer>anyPair()`.  This syntax explicitly sets the types needed without having to look beyond the invocation.

Comment: Second way: pass it in as `GenericsQ.<String, Integer>anyPair()`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?  I have never seen `GenericsQ` before and can't find anything about it.

Comment: That was the classname where the method is been definied in. Polygenelubricants edited it to `ExampleA`.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that explains why I didn't see it.  I added that to my answer since I was wrong about there only being 1 way to fix it.

Comment: This is not convincing enough for me. If type inference works for the variable assignment, then it should also work for actual parameters. Local variables have types, but so do formal parameters. Just as the compiler can use the type of the local variable to help with inference, so it should use the type of the formal parameter as well.

Comment: The reason the variable assignment works is that you have specified the variable's type.  `Pair<String,Integer> p = anyPair();` can just look at what it is being assigned to and infer types from that.  `process(p, anyPair());` cannot look at `process` until it has determined the types of each of it's parameters to determine what signature to use.  You could have a `static <F,S> void process(Pair<F,S> p1, Object p2)` method as well, so the compiler needs to evaluate the parameters first.  That means it can't take any information from the method signature including type inference.

Answer (score 0):

### Why:

`Collections.emptySet()` is trying to infer the type to return.  It's unable because E could be `Object` or `String`.  Both are valid matches for process.  Generic parameters are always invariant by default, not contravariant.  That means that `Integer extends Number` but `List<Integer>` does **not** extend `List<Number>`.  It **does** extend `List<? extends Number>`, however.

### Solutions:

Use an assignment to infer the type:

```
public <E> void process(Set<E> s1, Set<E> s2) { return; }

public void main(String[] args) {
   Set<String> s = Collections.emptySet();  // add this line
   process(new HashSet<String>(), s);
}
```

Explicitly write the type:

```
public <E> void process(Set<E> s1, Set<E> s2) { return; }

public void main(String[] args) {
   process(new HashSet<String>(), Collections.<String>emptySet()); //notice <String>
}
```

Allow contravariance explicitly (this is probably not what you want, however):

```
public <E> void process(Set<E> s1, Set<? super E> s2) { // added "super"
  return;
}

public void main(String[] args) {
   process(new HashSet<String>(), Collections.emptySet());
}
```