# Uses for the strange-looking explicit type argument declaration syntax in Java

Tags: java, generics, syntax, types

I recently came upon the strange syntax for explicitly declaring generic types when calling Java methods. For example:

```
Collections.<String>emptyList();
```

returns an empty `List<String>`. However, this seems silly as the implementation of `<T> emptyList()` is just the unchecked type cast `(List<T>) EMPTY_LIST`, such that all results have the same type erasure (and are the same object.) Moreover, this sort of explicit type declaration is usually not needed because the compiler can often infer the types:

```
List<String> empty = Collections.emptyList();
```

After doing some more digging I found two other times where you'd want to use this syntax, and they're all due to using the Guava library and **apparently trying to put too many statements on one line**.

1. Decorating a collection, for example with a synchronized wrapper, and the compiler being not able to infer the types. The following doesn't work if you take out the type declaration: `cannot convert from Set<Object> to Set<String>`:

   ```
   Set<String> set = Collections.synchronizedSet(Sets.<String>newHashSet());
   ```
2. Getting less specific type parameters when they compiler tries to make ones that are too specific. For example, without the type declaration the following statement complains as well: `cannot convert from Map<String, String> to Map<String, Object>`:

   ```
   Map<String, Object> toJson = ImmutableMap.<String, Object>of("foo", "bar");
   ```

I find it ironic that in the first case the inferred type parameters are too general and in the second case they are too specific, but I suppose that is just an artifact of the generics system in Java.

However, this language construct itself seems to be avoidable except in these [strange use cases invented by the Guava team](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=883). Moreover, it seems plain to me that **there *is* a way for the compiler to infer type arguments in both the above examples**, and the developers just chose not to do so. Are there examples of it ever being necessary or useful to use this construct in Java programming or does it exist solely to make the compiler simpler / JDK developer's life easier?

Comment: +1 I have thankfully never seen this notation before

Comment: Note that the authors of Guava didn't *invent* these use cases - they just grappled with them extensively because the use cases are particularly exposed by that library's semantics.

Comment: If you didn't use the Guava static methods here, you'd still have to explicitly specify the type arguments, just with a different syntax -- e.g. `Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>())`.

Comment: Note that in all the examples given here explicit type arguments are no longer necessary. This is because type inference improved much in Java 8.

Answer (score 5):

How is "shutting up the compiler" not "necessary or useful?" I find it both necessary *and* useful for my code to compile.

There are times when the correct type cannot be inferred, as you have already found. In such cases, it is necessary to [explicitly specify the type parameters](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20explicit%20type%20argument%20specification?). Some examples of the compiler just not being smart enough:

- [Why can't javac infer generic type arguments for functions used as arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14651589/139010)
- [Generics type inference fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4149825/139010)

And if you *really* want to dig into the complexities of type inference, it starts and ends with the Java Language Specification. You'll want to focus on [JLS §15.12.2.7. Inferring Type Arguments Based on Actual Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7) and [§15.12.2.8. Inferring Unresolved Type Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.8).

Comment: If you want to put it that way, are you saying there was no way to add generics to the Java language such that this did not have to exist? Seems like the compiler could have been designed to infer the arguments in all the examples I provided, but whoever implemented it just chose not to. I've edited my question slightly so you may want to update your answer.

Comment: Java generics have many deficiencies, including but not limited to imperfect type inference, type erasure, lack of collection covariance, and so on. In some world, sure, type inference in your Guava examples might be possible, but we do not live in that world. Guava was written to work with this world's Java compiler and flawed generic type system, so we work with what we've got.

Comment: And in case you're wondering, many of the shortcomings with Java's generic type system stem from the original decision to implement generics in a backwards-compatible manner.

Answer (score 1):

I found at least one case where the compiler infers the types correctly, and it's still needed: when you want to use the result as a more generic type. Take this method, which basically creates a `List<T>` from zero or more `T` objects:

```
public static <T> List<T> listOf(T... items) {
    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T item : items)
        list.add(item);

    return list;
}
```

The idea is that you can use it like this:

```
List<Integer> numbers = ListUtils.listOf(1, 2, 3);
```

Now, suppose you have a method that can receive `List<Object>`:

```
public static void a(List<Object> objs) {
    ...
}
```

and that you want to supply a list built via the `listOf()` method:

```
a(ListUtils.listOf(1, 2, 3));
```

This will not compile, as the method parameter type is `List<Object>` and the supplied argument is `List<Integer>`. In that case, we can change the invocation to:

```
a(ListUtils.<Object>listOf(1, 2, 3));
```

which does compile, as expected.

Comment: In the given example, a better solution might be to make the method parameter `List<? extends Object>`, which would accept a `List<Integer>`. However, this prohibits the method from adding anything besides `null` to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Java type inference is incredibly weak.  The only time it is not necessary to include the explicit type in a generic method like `emptyList()` is when the result of the method defines a variable.  If you try to pass an empty list as the argument of another method (example 1), a situation which arises for me on a daily basis (and I do not yet use Guava), the compiler just gives up on type inference completely.  I fail to see how declaring the empty list as a local, single-use variable is "putting too many statements on one line" as you call it; the empty list is a very simple sub-expression, except that Java's miserable type inference makes it complex. Compare with Scala, which will do inference in 3 different situations.

Comment: I don't see how "the result of the method defines a variable" does not extend to something like `synchronizedSet()` where the type `<T>` is passed straight through the method, so it should be able to infer what the type should be for whatever was passed in.

Comment: I agree; it's pathetic.  But that is the language spec.  The empty set call is an argument, but inference is only allowed at the top level.  This type of example is very common in my code, unfortunately, because the alternatives are even worse.